# Простая задача

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Второй день программирую на Objective-c,не могу решить!
Есть строка 2+2
Как посчитать это?

Comment: Я имею ввиду  2+2-это значение переменной str NSString типа.
Как мне сделать так чтобы это значение этой переменной считалось?
Можете написать что надо писать в коде?

Comment: 2+2 - это реально то, что вам нужно посчитать или же просто пример?

Answer (score 3):

Если это просто выражение типа `a+b`, то можно сделать так: *все что слева от плюса скопировать в одно число, что справа -- в другое и сложить*.

Если же это просто пример выражения, как уже заметил VioLet, то это значительно сложнее -- придется делать парсер.

p.s. Если, вдруг, захотите перейти на C++, то есть замечательная библиотека -- `Boost::Spirit`, которая просто идеально Вам подойдет!

Comment: На родном Objective-C тоже есть пара библиотек для таких целей: [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser), [GCMathParser](http://apptree.net/parser.htm).   
  
@Sergey4590 вообще, существует встроенный компонент для подобных вычислений: [NSExpression](http://www.google.ru/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=NSExpression&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=Y44GUOlD1MTiBNWmxa0J).

Comment: А как его использовать чтобы посчитать выражение записанное в строке?

Comment: Я про NSExpression)

Comment: Вот дана строка str=@"2+2*2"
Как посчитать с NSExpression?Напишите пожста код

Answer (score 2):

Строка это массив. Первый и третий элемент это числа, а второй элемент это действие. Проверяйте второй элемент и исполняйте соответствующие действие с первым и третьим элементом строки.

Comment: А код не подскажите,я просто только начал программировать на Objective-c